# How to define format of JSON to output with SailsJS?

Tags: json, rest, format, sails.js

We're using SailsJS as JSON REST server only, without html frontend. However we have to define format of JSON to output.

As I currently see, there are two ways to specify json format:

1. In a model. `module.exports.attributes.toJSON()`

   - Parallel. You cannot do async staff here.
   - Stateless. No way to define different formats for `find()` and `findOne()`.
2. In a controller.

   - In that case you will loose [Blueprints](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/blueprint-api) sugar.

I believe, the right way will be to use something like views for HTML frontend but for JSON. Are there any existing solutions for that?

Comment: In v.012.x, model instance methods? Which are dropped in v1 but you can have custom model methods: http://0.12.sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/models#?custom-model-methods ~ Just wondering, what is wrong with `res.json({ key: value })`: http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/response-res/res-json?